# How to trap nested SMTPAddressFailedException

Tags: java, email-validation

My app has a loop over email recipients, some of whom might have bad addresses. When a bad one is encountered, I'd like it reported to the user and the loop to continue. The problem is even though I trap all possible exceptions, the SMTPAddressFailedException gets trapped instead by javax:

*javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table*

and the remaining recipients get skipped. What's the proper way to handle this?

Here's the code;

```
            List<Entry> theEntries = theConcours.GetEntriesList();
        for(Entry entry : theEntries){
            MasterPersonExt mp = aConcours.GetMasterPersonnelObject().GetMasterPerson(entry.GetOwnerUnique()) ;
            String owneremail = mp.getEmail();
            String ownername = mp.getFirstName() + " " + mp.getLastName();
            curOwnerUniqueName = mp.getUniqueName();
            System.out.println("Processing " + mp.getUniqueName() + " email: " + owneremail);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
            try {  
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailuser));
                System.out.println("From set while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName);
            } catch (AddressException ex) {
                String msg = "AddressException for: " + mailuser + " while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName;
                //Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                okDialog(msg);
                aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
               // Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                String msg = "MessagingException for: " + mailuser + " while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName;
                //Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                okDialog(msg);
                aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
            }
            try {  
                message.setSubject("Your JCNA Concours Entry");
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
               // Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                String msg = "MessagingException setting Subject while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName ;
                //Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                okDialog(msg);
                aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
            }
            InternetAddress ownerInternetAddr;
             try {
                ownerInternetAddr = new InternetAddress(owneremail);
            } catch (AddressException ex) {
                String msg = "Bad judge eMail address for " + curOwnerUniqueName + "  \"" + mp.getEmail() + "\"";
                okDialog(msg);
                Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
            }
            try {
                ///
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, ownerInternetAddr);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
               // Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                String msg = "MessagingException setting TO while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName + "  \"" + mp.getEmail() + "\"";
                okDialog(msg);
                Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
            }
            String ownerFirst = entry.GetOwnerFirst();
            String  entryplacard = "http://www.concoursbuilder.us/manual-uploads/" + theConcours.GetHostClub() + "/" + concoursName + "/Placards/" + entry.GetOwnerLast() + "_" +  entry.GetUniqueDescription() + "-Placard.pdf";
            String jagModel = entry.GetModel();
            String[] theVals = {ownerFirst, jagModel, concoursName, judgingStarts, lunchTime,
                                awardsTime, concoursChairFirstLastName, concoursChairEmail, entryplacard, schedbyclass};
            messageContent  = replaceTagsWithValues(content_template, theTags, theVals);
            try {
                message.setContent(messageContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                String msg = "MessagingException setting Content while processing " + curOwnerUniqueName + "  \"" + mp.getEmail() + "\"";
                okDialog(msg);
                Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
                continue;
           }
            //send the message  
            try {
                Transport.send(message); 
                System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  
            } catch (SMTPAddressFailedException ex){
                String msg = "SMTPAddressFailedException while processing Owner " + ownername + " email address " + owneremail + " is invalid.";
                System.out.println(msg);
                okDialog(msg);
                aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex); 
                continue;
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
               // Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                String msg = "MessagingException while processing Owner " + ownername + " email address " + owneremail;
                System.out.println(msg);
                okDialog(msg);
                aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex); 
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe create another list... (done list) for the entries already gone threw.. and call a function which takes the whole list and the list of dones (empty at first).  Run the loop skipping any that are contained in the done list... add to the list of dones as you go.  Call the function again when exception is thrown.

Comment: OR, create a copy of the entries list in the function and remove the values as you go through... then re-call the function with the copied list when exception is caught.  You may also want to call a function which removes the e-mail from the source data when that exception is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by implementing a helper function called sendMailToAnEntrant() The for-loop then has a single call to sendMailToAnEntrant() in a try-catch. This results in the exception thrown by the javax code to be trapped. Seems to work.

```
            for(Entry entry : theEntries){
        try {
            //sendMailToAnEntrant(Concours aConcours, String aFromEmailAddress, String aSubject, String aContentTemplate, String [] aTags, Entry aEntry, Session aSession)
            sendMailToAnEntrant(aConcours, mailuser, "Your JCNA Concours Entry", content_template, theTags, entry, session);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            MasterPersonExt mp = aConcours.GetMasterPersonnelObject().GetMasterPerson(entry.GetOwnerUnique()) ;
            String owneremail = mp.getEmail();
            String ownername = mp.getFirstName() + " " + mp.getLastName();

            String msg = "Messaging Exception in sendMailToAnEntrant() for: " + ownername + " Email: " + owneremail;
            System.out.println(msg);
            okDialog(msg);
            aConcours.GetLogger().log(Level.INFO, msg, ex);
            //Logger.getLogger(SendMailSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            continue;
        }
```